# How can I strip substrings from retrieved data attribute values with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I’m using attr() CSS function to retrieve the values of attributes of an element:

HTML:

```
<div class="othermeta"
     data-name="name@Classification"
     data-content="content@Public" />
```

CSS:

```
div.othermeta:after {
    content: attr(data-name) ": " attr(data-content);
}
```

The result is as expected:

name@Classification: content@Public

Now I would like to strip out "name@" and "content@" from the retrieved attribute values so that the result looks like this instead:

Classification: Public

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this without JavaScript?

```css
div.othermeta:after {
    content: attr(data-name) ": " attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<div class="othermeta"
     data-name="name@Classification"
     data-content="content@Public" />
```

Comment: Sure, with JavaScript it would be easy, but in the project I'm working on, Javascript is not an option and changing the attribute values to come with out the prefixes before the @ is not an option as well.

Comment: You could erase the `name@` by using a negative `text-indent` (note that you need to add `display: block` as well). But like isherwood says... CSS is a markup language, no scripting language. So you either change the source or you alter it with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS isn't a scripting language. While it does have a few function-like features, it doesn't do string parsing.

You *could* bang things into shape by using both of the available pseudo-elements, but it's extremely fragile. Any change in font size, font family, etc. breaks it.

```css
.othermeta {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.othermeta:before,
.othermeta:after {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff; /* critical for masking */
}

/* note reverse order for proper layering */
.othermeta:after {
  content: attr(data-name) ": ";
  transform: translateX(-53px);
  padding-right: .5rem; /* word spacing */
}

.othermeta:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  transform: translateX(40px);
}

/* override for different name attribute value */
.othermeta[data-name^="name@Other"]:before {
  transform: translateX(76px);
}
```

```html
<div class="othermeta" data-name="name@Classification" data-content="content@Public">
  &nbsp;
</div>

<div class="othermeta" data-name="name@OtherClassification" data-content="content@Private">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, isherhood. This helps. I completely understand that this is not stable and "responsive". Ultimately, the devs of the web application will fix it, but for the next half year or so, this "hack" will do it :-)